# RSS Feed Behaviour (Inc. Feedburner)

Tags: rss, feed

I have a self hosted Wordpress site (latest update as of time of posting) that I am using to host a podcast that I am starting.

In order to minimise any future hassles should I have to change hosting for any reason, I chose to run the feeds though Feedburner, and get people to subscribe to those also.  That way, I can move and repoint if required in the future.

I installed a plugin (FD Feedburner) that redirects to my feed burner URL, but I have found that this only works for http://etc.com/feed URLS.  When for example Safari detects the feed, if a user clicks the RSS button in Safari rather than one of my links, it opens the Wordpress original feed via feed://etc.com/feed. - Obviously this still works, but it splits my subscribers into 2 pools that makes tracking difficult.

What is considered best practice for this sort of thing, is there any way to edit the built in RSS feeds (remove comments Feed etc, stop Safari detecting the RSS feed) and remove the Atom feed option while I am at it?

Many thanks,
Dan

Comment: Are there any "link" or "meta" tags in your header that could be pointing Safari - like <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml"... > ?

Answer (score 2):

Adding this in your theme's functions.php removes the RSS meta link markup on all pages of your wordpress site, which means browsers won't be able to detect any RSS feeds on your pages:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse58023_wp_head', 1 );
function wpse58023_wp_head() {

    // Removes main feed link(s)
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'feed_links', 2 );

    // Removes comments feed link
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'feed_links_extra', 3 );

}
```

For instance, the above function removes this markup on home page (feeds differ on different pages):

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="My Website Feed" href="/feed/" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="My Website Comments Feed" href="/comments/feed/" />
```

So now, browsers will think that your home page has no feed. What you can then do is, add something like this in your header.php (before the `</head>` tag):

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="My Website Feed" href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/mywebsite" />
```

Use [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) to show different feeds on different pages. That should give you an idea as to what you can do.